# Is there a way to know when my app switches from Suspended to another state?

Tags: ios

I'm having issues with my `WKWebView`s'cache being purged sometimes when a user hasn't been using my app for a while.

I guess, that's because iOS puts my app in `Suspended` and then a low-memory condition occurs so my app is purged.

I read Apple's documentation about [The App Life Cycle - Execution States for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3)

Especially the part describing the `Suspended` state :

> Suspended - The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system
>   moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before
>   doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not
>   execute any code. **When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may
>   purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the
>   foreground app**.

Two questions here :

1) What does "purge" mean exactly ? The app is killed ? Or does it still appear on the app selector ( when double-tapping the home button )

2) Here we can see that there is no way to know when an app is going to be suspended. All right. But if a user comes back to the app, is there a way to know, then, that the app has been suspended ? I can't find any `UIAppDelegate`'s method to do so, but there might be another solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Purge - The purge command forces disk and memory caches to be emptied,
>   offering a ‘cold disk buffer cache’ which is similar to the state of
>   the operating system after a reboot.

Referenced from [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/24/free-up-inactive-memory-in-mac-os-x-with-purge-command/)

As per the documentation

> [applicationDidEnterBackground:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground)—Lets you know that your app is now
>   running in the background and may be suspended at any time.

This is the only method which will let you know that method may will enter in Suspended State

also

> [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) will let you now that
>   your app's launch process is almost done and the app is almost ready
>   to run.

Answer (score 0):

> The app is in the background but is not executing code

I think it's explained good by Apple, the app is still in memory but no background threads are executed since foreground app requires more resources. Maybe when memory is restored, your app can execute background code again if has not been killed by OS.

When low-memory condition occurs, you're app could be killed (purge).

> Is there a way to know, then, that the app has been suspended?

When app is killed from OS, next launch is equal to a complete new restart of app. For this AppDelegate doesn't provide a method to achieve this. You could set a flag in UserDefaults when app goes in background and then make some logic on that flag.